# Oracle 11g server rename issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, oracle, oracle-11g

So we set up an Oracle server out of production (11g on Server 2008 x64) and our plan was to just rename the server's hostname to move it into production.  Well, the database itself is functioning but every time we try to launch the management tool, it spawns up a bazillion and one processes (ever increasing) and at some point may end up causing the server to crash.

Is anyone familiar with Oracle issues pertaining to renaming of servers and the management tool failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the config files for the database specific DBCONSOLE in your ORACLE_HOME under a direcory named with the FQDN of the Host, an underscore, and the SID. eg

```
myhost.mynetwork_mydatabase
```

You could try stopping the dbconsole with

```
set ORACLE_SID=mydatabase
emctl stop dbconsole
```

Then fiddling with the config files and dir names and then restarting the console.

If that doesn't work then you can reinstall the dbconsole into a database with command line tools. I'd lookup the full set of help on EMCTL.

Update: I had to recreate some DBCONSOLE repositories recently.

The following steps worked well.

Manual DBCONSOLE removal and recreation

```
1. Remove the existing Windows Service
    Remove HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\OracleDBConsole[SID]

2. Remove the existing setup from the filesystem
    Delete %ORACLE_HOME%\DomainName_SID
    Delete %ORACLE_HOME%\oc4j\j2ee\OC4J_DBConsole_DomainName_SID

3. Remove the SYSMAN schema from the database as SYS or SYSTEM
    drop user sysman cascade;
    drop role MGMT_USER;
    drop user MGMT_VIEW cascade;
    drop public synonym MGMT_TARGET_BLACKOUTS;
    drop public synonym SETEMVIEWUSERCONTEXT;

4. Run the Database Configuration Assistant
    Select the database from the list
    Ensure that the DBCONSOLE option and the Enterprise Manager Repository options are ticked
```

Answer (score 0):

From Shirish, comments below.

"Hostname wont affect anything for database as long as its mapped correctly in /etc/hosts

for tools (such as OEM or grid.. hostname is sometimes added in repository or the config files) ..unless you want to poke around for all those entries, best way will be to do a re-install (completely clean old install and then install again) of that tool . ( and usually its the fastest way too )"

Please let us know if you need any specific instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Is there any way to just completely reinstall the Enterprise Management Console alone without having to completely reinstall the DB product?  If so could you give us those instructions on how to do so.

Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: You can re-install EM using OUI. Both EM and ORacle Software are installed in Separate Oracle Homes.  When you launch OUI, you need to provide EM home (And not oracle home)

Answer (score 0):

Yep - what cephas said.  I was able to do this by renaming the 
    .../product/11.1.0/db_1/oc4j/j2ee/OC4J_DBConsole_oldhostname_orcl 
 to
    .../product/11.1.0/db1_oc4j/j2ee/OC4J_DBConsole_newhostname_orcl .

after which i had it rebuild the em repository with:
    emca -config dbcontrol db -repos recreate